# Where am I going wrong in this Gram-Schmidt calculation?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two vectors:

$$a_1=(2, 1, 2),\quad a_2=(3, 1, 0)$$

I want to decompose $a_2$ into an orthogonal and a parallel component with respect to $a_1$. So first I project it onto $a_1$:

$$\langle a_1, a_2\rangle\frac {a_1} {||a_1||}=7\frac {a_1} 3=\frac13(14, 7, 14)$$

Now I subtract that from $a_2$ to get the orthogonal component:

$$(3, 1, 0)-\frac13(14, 7, 14)=-\frac13(5, 4, 14)$$

But that's clearly not orthogonal to $a_1$. $(2, 1, 2)\cdot(5, 4, 14)$ is obviously not $0$ since it's a sum of positive terms.

Which step am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, $\| a_1 \|$ should be $\| a_1 \|^2$.

Roughly speaking, we're only interested in the direction of $a_1$, so we need to get rid of its length each time we multiply by $a_1$. It occurs once in the dot product, and once by actual multiplication.

Comment: Once to normalize $a_1$, and once again to cancel out the factor of $||a_1||$ from the scalar product?

Comment: @JackM: Yep! (Which you typed as I was editing it into my answer)